# Sending the firebase device token to server using angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-notifications

firebase.service.ts

The code below is the firebase service in my angular2 app. The configuration file is in app.module.ts. I want to send the device token id to the server. Everything works fine, but the "this.http.post(....)" portion do not work.

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
    import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';

    import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
    import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';

    import * as firebase from 'firebase';
    import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
    import { ErrorModel } from '../_models/index';

    @Injectable()
    export class FirebaseService {
        private messaging;
        private errors = ErrorModel;

        constructor(private authService:AuthService, private http:Http) {
          this.messaging = firebase.messaging();
        }

        request_permission_for_notifications(){
            this.messaging.requestPermission().then(()=>{
              return firebase.messaging().getToken();
            }).then(token=>{
              if(this.authService.is_logged_in){
                let options = this.authService.get_header();
                let api_url = '/api/subscribe-device';
                this.http.post(api_url,{token:token},options).map((response:Response)=>response.json());
              }else{
                console.log({success:false,message:this.errors.not_logged_in_error});
              }
            }).catch(err=>{
              console.log('Unable to get permission to notify.', err);
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: check your console for error ?

Comment: @PardeepJain  There is not any error in the console.

Answer (score 0):

```
request_permission_for_notifications(){
      return new Promise<string>((resolve, reject)=>{
        this.messaging.requestPermission().then(function(){
          return firebase.messaging().getToken();
        }).then(function(token){
          resolve(token);
        }).catch(function(err){
          console.log('Unable to get permission to notify.', err);
        });
      });
    }

subscribe_device(token:string){
      if(this.authService.is_logged_in()){
        let options = this.authService.get_header();
        let api_url = '/api/subscribe-device';
        return this.http.post(api_url,{token:token},options).map((response:Response)=>response.json());
      }else{
        console.log({success:false,message:this.errors.not_logged_in_error});
      }
    }
```

I used promise to resolve my token, and then i use the new function "subscribe_token" to post my token to the server.